# When accessing Local Websties - NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: laravel

All my local sites are **.test** but for some reason when I access *some* of them i get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

What's weird is that the error message points to another local environment.

> This server couldn't prove that it's *****c.test; its security
> certificate is from ******ing.test. This may be caused by a
> misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I tried deleting the certificate but nothing happened.

> ********ing.test Issued by: Laravel Valet CA Self Signed CN Expires: Saturday, January 21, 2023 at 17:09:55 Eastern Standard Time
> "****ing.test" certificate name does not match input

I'm hiding the URL's for privacy purposes.

Comment: Have you tried dnsflush from your local env?

Comment: it means you're reusing the same cert for other local sites that don't match the cert name.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by updating my updating my valet from  2.18.9 to 3.2 and running `valet secure`.